# How can gnu_ddrescue be resumed to wipe a hard disk?

Tags: dd, ddrescue

Hard drives (non-SSD) are generally wiped with the command `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdX conv=fsync status=progress`. Since power outages do occur, this lends to restarting the wipe process multiple times. Additionally, there are often requirements to move equipment.

`dd` as far as i know and based on my research does not support the ability to resume interruptions.

Posts on `ddrescue` are primarily focused on copying bitwise data from source to destination. Additionally they are concerned about resuming the [copying process](https://superuser.com/questions/431815/how-to-resume-ddrescue-process).

Based on a post to [wipe unwritable sectors,](https://superuser.com/questions/222328/how-to-erase-a-hard-drive-with-unwritable-sectors) it suggests that `ddrescue` can be used to wipe disks.

Can `ddrescue` be resumed if wiping disks and if so how when using a live CDs or DVDs?

Alternatively, what other options are there if `ddrescue` is unable to support this requirement?

`ddrescue` is not currently in use. If it does support the requirement to resume an interrupted process, it'll be used going forward.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? Is this a theoretical question or are you already using `ddrescue`? If you are using it - what exactly are you doing? I can think of ways to wipe a hard drive with ddrescue but it's not what it was designed to do...

Comment: @frostschutz - I have updated the question with a post that touches on the use of `ddrescue`.

Comment: If want to quickly zero a disk, don't use `/dev/urandom` as a first pass.  It's probably better to fill the drive with zero bits first.  That will destroy almost all the data very quickly... then do the random bit flipping... with a final flip back to zero.... Unless you are looking for MIL-spec procedures... and for that I would recommend using something like [wipe](https://github.com/berke/wipe) ... but definitely not manually run `dd` commands.

Comment: @RubberStamp - Can you reference an authoritative source that touches on writing zeros first? References such as Arch Linux for example (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Securely_wipe_disk#Preparations_for_block_device_encryption) suggest otherwise. It also appears that `wipe` is no longer maintained - (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Securely_wipe_disk#wipe). Why do you say not to manually run `dd` commands?

Comment: @RubberStamp You actually don't need to do multiple wipes. It's totally fine to do a single overwrite.

Comment: @Motivated :  It doesn't really matter what is written *first* all that matters is that all bits are flipped at least once.  So, write all ones and then zeros ... or write all zeros and then ones and then back to zeros should flip all bits ...

Comment: @frostschutz - Why has the question been put on hold? What is unclear about the question?

Comment: @RalfFriedl - - Why has the question been put on hold? What is unclear about the question? It would be helpful that there is context as to it being put on hold.

Comment: @terdon - I have been seeking clarification on why the question has been put on hold however there hasn't been any response. Can someone please provide a clear explanation as to why it has been put on hold so that if need be i can amend the question?

Comment: @Mr Shunz - I have been seeking clarification on why the question has been put on hold however there hasn't been any response. Can someone please provide a clear explanation as to why it has been put on hold so that if need be i can amend the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `ddrescue` for this. You can use plain `dd` and make it print progress when wiping:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdX bs=256k 2>/media/usb/progress.txt &
while kill -USR1 $!; do sleep 10; done
```

This will begin wiping the disk, sending the process to the background, and then telling it to write its progress to a log file kept on a USB stick every 10 seconds. If the power is cut, you will be able to see approximately where it was left off, and then will be able to resume wiping from that position:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdX bs=256k seek=<number of records>
```

A single pass overwrite with random data is [sufficient](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/10474/106285) to make all data unrecoverable.

Comment: It depends on what standard and/or attack the OP is concerned about ... Mil-STD does several writes and also uses algorithmic write patterns across the disk itself ... Certifying that all data are not readable from the surface of a disk even under an electron microscope... [Gutmann wipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gutmann_method) ... Those COMSEC custodians can be rather difficult to work around...

Comment: @RubberStamp That is an old data destruction myth that has been retracted by the author himself. On modern high-density hard drives, a single pass with random data is sufficient to make it unreadable with any technology. Consider the fact that even low-density analog audio tape cannot be recovered after a single overwrite. As for the relevant government standards, those no longer specify multiple overwrites and instead demand physical destruction to get around the risk of damaged unwritable sectors retaining data.

Comment: Using `/dev/urandom` as the one and only write across the drive does not guarantee that all bits are flipped. So, the premise of your claim in your comment to the OP is not accurate...  A 35 pass Gutmann is the extreme... a single pass pseudo-random write is worse than writing all ones in a single pass...  Writing all zeros as a first pass would allow the OP to seek through the drive until the first non-zero bit and restart the zero process... Using a pre-built wiping program ensures that someone "out-there" has thought more deeply about the security of the algorithm than the non-expert.

Comment: @RubberStamp I think you are misunderstanding how hard drives store data. When you write a zero or a one, you aren't writing that literal bit to the disk due to a heavy amount of modulation (a null sector will be physically written as a pseudorandom stream of 512 bits with a few extra bits for ECC). Furthermore even if you did, a zero is not the absence of a bit. They are nothing more than flipped magnetic polarization. Which is one and which is zero is _completely arbitrary_. This has been true since MFM drives and still is today.

Comment: Due to the modulation, flipping 0→0 or 1→1 is exactly as "destructive" to the bit 0→1 or 1→0.

Comment: Demonstrate, through particular experiment or external research paper that `/dev/urandom` guarantees that all bits are flipped in one pass.

Comment: @RubberStamp Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88000/discussion-between-forest-and-rubberstamp).

Comment: We've been here before... you've made a claim and provided an answer... you can greatly improve on the discussion by amending your answer to include the *why* and the logical along with practical research.

Comment: @RubberStamp Please use the above-linked chat if you want to further discuss this or want to hear extra reasoning. I don't want to clutter up the chat section.

Comment: @RubberStamp I have linked to another answer with more information, since I do not wish to answer a question OP did not ask (the question was about resuming a wipe, not about data destruction theory).

Comment: Your linked research has somewhat conflicting answers... and zero answers definitively indicate that a single pass of pseudo-random bits is sufficient.  As I wrote in other comments... **It depends on what standard and/or attack the OP is concerned about**

Comment: @RubberStamp The answer I linked provides both experimental results and expert analysis. For a _modern drive_, there is no known way to recover any amount of data. There is no such thing as absolute proof. No matter how much evidence says it cannot be recovered, you can counter by saying "so prove it!". I cannot prove a negative. And OP did not ask to formulate a threat model, but how to resume an overwrite.

Comment: @forest - Why is the command `2>/media/usb/progress.txt`? My understanding is that 2> is standard error? Would you also mind explaining the use of `while kill -USR1 $!; do sleep 10; done` including the purpose of `kill` and `-USR1` for example?

Comment: @Motivated That command takes the stderr from `dd`, because that's where it writes the output. As for `kill -USR1`, that tells `dd` to write the progress to stderr (`SIGUSR1` doesn't kill `dd`).

Comment: @forest - Why would it be standard error as opposed to standard output?

Comment: @Motivated I believe because the authors of `dd` know that you might want to do `dd if=foo | some_command` which means that it would have to write the _data_ to stdout. Because of this, the statistics and such are printed to stderr instead so it doesn't interfere with data that may be written to stdout.

Comment: @forest - That's makes sense. I wasn't aware that statistics for example would be written to standard error. My understanding was that it was limited to errors that needed to be written to the console.

Comment: @Motivated The names are such for legacy reasons. Generally stdout is the "main" output that you can pipe and redirect, and stderr is the "secondary" output that is, usually, simply displayed to the screen.